# SQL Server Query - retrieve multiple rows with max function

Tags: sql

I'm working on a c# desktop application where I'm iterating through a loop of all customers. Instead of performing a select statement for each individual customer I'm hoping I can do one query to gather rows for all customers.

```sql
SELECT CustID, Runtot 
FROM AUDIT
WHERE UID = (SELECT MAX(uid) FROM Audit WHERE CustID = 6)
```

Audit Table:
UID, CustID, CustIndex, Amount, RunTot

UID is an identity column, custindex iterates for every row a customer has inserted and the runtot field will go up and down depending on the amount. Basically what I need is the most recent runtot field by looking at the max uid or custindex for every customer.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C#? This is obviously a pure SQL question

Comment: Use a `GROUP BY CustID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.CustID, a.Runtot 
FROM AUDIT a
WHERE a.UID = (SELECT MAX(a2.uid) FROM Audit a2 WHERE a2.CustID = a.CustID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient (and in my opinion, cleanest) way to do this is with a With clause

```
WITH auditMax AS (
SELECT MAX(a.uid), a.CustID
FROM AUDIT a
GROUP BY a.CustID
)

SELECT a.CustID, a.Runtot 
FROM AUDIT a
INNER JOIN auditMax cte
   on a.CustId = cte.CustId
```